# Ubuntu 14.04 install "old lamp" stack for penetration testing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, wordpress

I am preparing WAF video for my team and I want to test a sample ubuntu server which will be my victim.

I'd like to install "old version" of packages and deploy Wordpress on top of it and use some CVE.

In my video I want to show "the before" state and "after" state.

In my case, any Linux distribution will work. I selected Ubuntu as I have the most experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for the package name (lets use nginx for now) you would search for the candidate like so :

`$ apt-cache policy nginx
nginx:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
     1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages
     1.14.0-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages`

Using the version table given, you can specify an older version like so :

`$ sudo apt install nginx=1.14.0-0ubuntu1`